# Request verified even _RequestVerificationToken without being passed in AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

I am trying to implement `HtmlAntiForgeryToken` in my MVC application for that
I have added  `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` on .cshtml page  and added `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute in controller. 
I am making an `AJAX POST` call to controller.

> But I didn't pass  `_RequestVerificationToken` as parameter in `AJAX`
>   call. Antiforgerytoken process says that request verification token
>   will be sent in cookie and also should be passed in form data, both
>   the values should match then only request is considered as valid
>   request.

But in my application even I didn't pass `@htmlantiforgerytoken()` attribute in HTML and also the `_RequestVerificationToken` in form data, request is being processed successfully without showing any invalid token error.

**html - commented the token attribute**

[image]

**IN JS**

[image]

**Controller**

[image]

> **The question here is, How RequestToken is being verified in controller without passing _RequestverificationToken parameter in AJAX call from js?**

Any Explanation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
newrole.__RequestVerificationToken = $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken ']").val();
```

Comment: Thanks mohammad. Yes i can pass like this. but without passing that parameter itself request is being verified. I wanted to know how it is verified.